# Creating a Server-only Realm

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Does Realm support the following use case?

1. Users would enter information about themselves, e.g. their interests and hobbies. I suppose this data can be saved in Synced Realm(s).
2. Users need to query if there are other users having certain interests and hobbies.  On a relational DB, this would be a simple query against the users' table(s).

On Realm, would this be a query against the "collection" of ALL Users' Realms? Is this supported? **Can I send a query, which accesses multiple Realms (a query, which considers multiple realms as a one data set)?**

If this is not possible, **should I create a server-only Realm,** which would store a read-only "cumulative" copy for all of the Users' Synced Realms? By a server-only realm, I mean a realm, which is NOT synced to users' devices. This realm would be huge in size and not suitable for syncing to every user's device.

Thanks for your effort and time in trying to answer my question...

Comment: Yes, Realm can do that pretty easily and this would also be a simple query against the users 'table' in Realm. If you have a massive amount of data, tens of thousands of users, you may want to use a Query Based Sync instead of a Full Sync to reduce the size of the data you are working with on the device.

Comment: @Jay Thank you for the comment. When you said Realm can do that, were you referring to (1) a query against the "collection" of ALL Users' Realms, or (2) a server-only Realm?

Comment: Does Realm support the following use case: Yes to both 1) and 2). It would be a 'simple' query that may or may not involve relational data but it can be done either way.

Comment: Also note that while this is a valid question, it's probably not the best question for SO. It's super broad and not detailed. Therefore there really isn't an answer because we don't know specifically what you're asking. Take a look at the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you can write some code and provide some details we can probably bang out a dynamite answer to a specific question.